# Android Divide layout into section and assign counter to it

Tags: android, layout, view

I am working on a project to test user behavior.  Here is my XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/TouchArea"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#800ff4ff" >

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/grid1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/grid2"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/grid3"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/grid3"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/grid4"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid8"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid7"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid9"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid10"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid10"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/grid7"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid11"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid10"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid12"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/grid11"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid13"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid9"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid14"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grid13"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid15"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/grid11"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid16"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid12"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how it looks like, 16 girds inside a relative layout.

[image]!

What I want to do is assign counter to each layout, whenever ueser's finger cross this grid the counter wll plus 1.  However when I try to add touchListener and override the onTouch method it throws the null pointer exception so I need to call dispatchTouchEvent.  But in dispatchTouchEvent I am not sure how to get each view seperately.  Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `android:clickable="true"` for each of your clickable layouts.  Then you could implement `OnClickListener` to catch each event.

```
public class MyClass implements View.OnClickListener {

    // set your on click listeners in onCreate or something

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.grid1:
                // do something
            case R.id.grid2:
                // do something
            case R.id.grid3:
                // do something

                // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems works for me. Although I need to continuing get all the event until finger relase, so I just change to onTouch and only get id when action equals to down.